# I have a java code ,cannot understand interface

Tags: java, interface

Here is the code
i have three interfaces

```
interface i1{ 
int x=1;
}
interface i2{ 
int x=2;
}
interface i3{ 
int x=3;
}
class A implements i1,i2,i3{
system.out.println(x); // It shows Field is ambgous
}
```

How to answer this or how to overcome this problem.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to make a choice between the 3 different variables with the same name? Prefix your variable name with the name of the interface. : `i3.x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to answer this or how to overcome this problem.

Don't use fields in interfaces, or if you *must* use them, and they *must* have the same names, just fully qualify them:

```
System.out.println(i3.x);
```

Note that with `import static`, the "brevity" reason for importing interfaces containing constants is removed - interfaces should really only be implemented for genuine behavioural reasons. See Effective Java 2nd edition for more advice on this front.

Answer (score 0):

This is because same field is defined in all interfaces hence it doesn't know which field to use among these 3 .

- You will have to specify interface name.
- Code should be in some init block or method.
- its `System.out.println` and not `system`

Also your names for types should start with capital leters

```
interface I1{ 
int x=1;
}
interface I2{ 
int x=2;
}
interface I3{ 
int x=3;
}
class A implements I1,I2,I3{
 static{
   System.out.println(I1.x);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the of the 3 interface variable x is there,so it shows ambiguous.
Compiler confuses to print which x from i1 or i2 or i3

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are designed to demonstrate a class structure. If you must declare fields in multiple interfaces and use all those interfaces in one class, you should explicitly declare which interface you're using for that variable.

```
System.out.println(i3.x);
```

You can also use the `extends` keyword in your interfaces to decrease ambiguity by setting up inheritance.

```
interface i1{int x=1;}
interface i2 extends i1 {...}
interface i3 extends i2 {...}
class A implements i3{...}
```

Class A will have to implement all functions declared in i1,i2 and i3.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. This is called **Constant Interface Antipattern**. Or just use the fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**though answer to this question has been given by many.

but there is some detailed analysis.

```
  interface I1{ 
  int x=1;
  }
  interface I2{ 
  int x=2;
  }
  interface I3{ 
  int x=3;
  }
  class A implements I1,I2,I3{
  static{
   System.out.println(I1.x);
  }

  }
```

the integer x is a  public final integer x.
the compiler internally **convert it as a final** means treats it as the constant.

that's why when the user prints the value of x the compiler gives the ambiguous error for this.

for practically implementation of this please use -javap tool which is in jdk.

**usage: javap I1**